# Excel 2016: to find the first occurance of a value in a vector

Tags: microsoft-excel, search-indexing, conditional-statements

I have a vertical vector (see below) and I am looking for a function where I can search for the first occurance of the "1" or a "2" or a "3". If I find the first "1" I would add a value to a cell and then do the same search for the first "2" and so on. Is it possible to achieve w/ Excel?

0

0

0

1

1

1

1

2

2

2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search separately then `MATCH` would be the function, used like this

`=MATCH(1,A2:A100,0)`

It returns the position of the value in the range, so in my example if the first 1 is in `A10`, for example, then that's the 9th cell of `A2:A100` so the result is 9

Comment: What is the best way to take the cell that match() returns and adds a value?

Comment: Do you mean to add a value to that actual cell, e.g. A10 in my example?

Comment: How do I use the reference I get from the A10 and transform the reference so I can add a value to any cell I want ?

Comment: OK, I'm not really clear on what you mean but INDEX might help, e.g. if you want to get the actual value of A10 you can use this formula `=INDEX(A2:A100,MATCH(1,A2:A100,0))` ....but as we already know that A10 =1 I'm not sure how useful that would be. You can also use INDEX to get the value of a cell in another column on the matching row, e.g. to get the value from C10 use `=INDEX(C2:C100,MATCH(1,A2:A100,0))`. Note that INDEX can return either a reference or a cell value, depending on how it is used.

Comment: @Alexander, whenever you find the occurrence Excel will literally return the same value,, like if you are searching the 2nd occurrence of 1,, is 1 in fact. So it doesn't makes any scene search like this. Better you think to find the Cell Address or the Row Number for the occurrence. Or value of adjacent cell.